# Job-Search Post: Commas, Hyphens

Tags: commas, clauses, hyphens

My friend has a translation business. He inquired if I could assist him for this: He posted on a job-search site to look for employees:

> “We look for some more people**,** to take **on-board**…”

Does he have to put a comma, there? He said he did it as a secondary clause. And, with **on-board**, would he have to hyphenate this?

Comment: Unless you're somebody like Captain Kirk, nobody would think there are two clauses in that sentence. *We look for [something].* What is that something? *some more people to take on board*, a single, unbroken phrase.

Comment: First of all, "look for some people" is flat out wrong.

Answer (score 0):

No a comma is not required there. Indeed one might argue that using a comma three is wrong. I am sure that I would not use one.

As to "on-board" vs "onboard", i would strongly favor omitting the hyphen. [This google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=onboard%2Con-board&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Conboard%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20-%20board%3B%2Cc0) shows the unhyphenated form more common since 2000, and slightly more common earlier, but not drastically so.

I would add that "we look for some people" would be more natural as "we **are looking** for some people".

Comment: I think a comma is OK but it slightly changes the structure of the sentence. "to take on-board" can modify "people" or the whole sentence.

Comment: Why not tell him his sentence is flawed? So he gets on board right and the rest be damned?? :)